How to intercept access in iframe and return local file in Electron?
Requirements: 1. Intercept the request and return the local file if it exists locally; 2. Regardless of whether it exists, it needs to be downloaded from the URL and saved locally.
I have searched various methods on the Internet but cannot meet the requirements, so I am looking for help.
Tried the following,
code segment
 mainWindow.webContents.session.webRequest.onBeforeRequest((details, callback) => {
                const fs = require('fs');
                const data = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
                const dataURL = `data:text/html;base64,${Buffer.from(data).toString('base64')}`;
                //(node:6140) electron: Failed to load URL 'Error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'
                return callback({
                  cancel: false,
                  data: dataURL,
                  mimetype: mimetype,
                  encoding,
                });
                //(node:16760) electron: Failed to load URL: 'Error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'
                return callback({
                  cancel: false,
                  data: fs.readFileSync(filePath),
                  mimeType: mimetype
                })
                //The URL will be changed, and the relative URLs within the web page will be confused.
                return callback({
                  redirectURL:someUrl
                })

});

